# rosmake or rosbuild?

Tags: ros, library, rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I want to develop some ROS packages which contain libraries for other packages to use, and have some questions about the development process:

1. Should I use rosmake or rosbuild to compile and build my packages?
2. Which files should I modify to create libraries (.so files) instead of executables?

Thanks,
HZ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11143/rosmake-or-rosbuild?/) by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the rosbuild wiki page:

"To build packages, use rosmake."

rosbuild is the name of the library of build-support tools; rosmake is the command you run to actually build stuff. Assuming you're developing your code just for ROS use (as distinct from implementing a ROS wrapper around some library that needn't be / isn't ROS-aware), you should do everything in CMakeLists.txt in your package's root directory. (Everything except setting the exports; that's in manifest.xml).

If you want to compile libraries, use the `rosbuild_add_library` macro; see the rosbuild wikipage for some examples, and the default CMakeLists.txt that roscreate-pkg gives you.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-09-07**:
If you like my answer, accept is (there's a checkbox). That way, more karma for me!

**Comment by [HZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/1054/hz/) on 2011-09-07**:
Thanks a lot. It seems I asked a silly question...   type in "rosbuild"  in terminal, and get: "rosbuild: command not found"